# A random walk on the $n$-hypercube

Tags: geometry, statistics, graph-theory, markov-chains

The stationary distribution for a simple random walk on a nonweighted graph gives

$$\pi _{v}=\frac{deg(v)}{\sum_{z}^{}deg(z)} = \frac{deg(v)}{2e},$$

where $e$ denotes the number of edges of the graph.

We can show this is stationary by proving that $\boldsymbol{\pi }=\boldsymbol{\pi }\boldsymbol{P}$.

$$(\pi P)_{v}=\sum_{w}\pi _{w}P_{wv}= \sum_{w\sim v}\frac{deg(w)}{2e}\frac{1}{deg(w)}=\frac{1}{2e}\sum_{w\sim v}1=\frac{deg(v)}{2e}=\pi _{v}.$$

To make use of this, we can look at the hypercube.

The $n$-hypercube graph has $2^{n}$ vertices.  The sum of the degrees of the vertices is $n2^{n}$.  So,

$$\pi _{v}=\frac{n}{n2^{n}}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}.$$

The distribution is uniform.  This is because all of the vertex degrees are the same.

How does this concept change when the graph is weighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a general graph on $n$ nodes. Let the weights be $w_{ij}\geq 0$, and assume $w_{ij} = w_{ji}$, so the graph is still undirected.  For all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ define $w_i$ as the sum of all weights out of node $i$:
$$ w_i = \sum_{k=1}^n w_{ik} $$
Assume $w_i>0$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. 
Assume transition probabilities satisfy: 
$$ P_{ij} = \frac{w_{ij}}{w_i} \quad \forall i, j \in \{1, ..., n\} $$
Note that we allow self-transitions if we have weights $w_{ii}>0$.

#### Claim:

The following probabilities $(\pi_i)_{i=1}^n$ satisfy the global balance equations (stationary equations): 
$$ \pi_i = A w_i \quad, \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
where $A = \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n w_j}$.

Proof: We can show these probabilities satisfy the *detail equations*: 
$$\pi_i P_{ij} = \pi_j P_{ji} \quad \forall i, j \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
and the detail equations imply that the same probabilities satisfy the global balance equations. $\Box$

If the resulting weighted graph is *connected* then the Markov chain is *irreducible* and this probability distribution is in fact the unique solution to the global balance equations.  For completeness, note that the global balance equations are: 
$$ \pi_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i P_{ij} \quad , \forall j \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
and a 2-line calculation shows that the detail equations imply the global balance equations.